# PayPal REST API issue in PPModel.php on line 51

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

Whenever I try to create payment on paypal using create.php, it gives me this error

> Fatal error: Class 'string' not found in
> public_html/demos/demo_files/integrate-paypal-rest-api-php-mysql/vendor/paypal/sdk-core-php/lib/PayPal/Common/PPModel.php
> on line 51

I am not able to find any help regarding it anywhere. PPModel.php is part of PHP SDK by PayPal.
PPModel.php can be found [here](https://github.com/paypal/sdk-core-php/blob/master/lib/common/PPModel.php)
The script works fine on localhost, but on webhosting server it gives following Fatal error.

**Update**
I was able to fix the issue by disabling eaccelerator for php.
Caching plugins such as eaccelerator, opcache, APC might create problem for others also