# Class "String" not found error in PayPal core sdk

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I am getting the following error all of sudden

> Fatal error: Class 'string' not found in
>   \vendor\paypal\sdk-core-php\lib\PayPal\Common\PPModel.php on line 51

Did anything change in recent Wordpress update?

Comment: Why would a WordPress update break a composer-installed version of the PayPal SDK? I'm not clear on why you bring WP up.

Comment: The site has been un changed for last 3 years. The only thing that has changed is WP version recently and then it broke on Paypal Checkout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Around March, 2015, PayPal made some big
changes with PHP-SDK 1.0.0
Part of that change was renaming some classes;
PPModel.php was changed to PayPalModel.php

There were a lot of other files renamed. 
Here is a link to all the breaking changes.

https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/wiki/Breaking-Changes---1.0.0

You will probably have a lot more work to do, other than just
PPModel.  I know I had
to change 23 files and 73 lines of code. This is 
because a lot of class files were renamed.

Comment: That doesn't explain the particular error message given, though.

Comment: This was exactly the problem. I just updated Paypal REST API SDK and then I had to modify my paypal.php code to match with new classes.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not sure why it's started happening to you right now, but I can see the bug:

- [the line mentioned](https://github.com/paypal/sdk-core-php/blob/master/lib/common/PPModel.php#L51) initialises a class based on some reflected parameters
- [the reflection helper it calls defaults to returning "string"](https://github.com/paypal/sdk-core-php/blob/master/lib/common/PPReflectionUtil.php#L22), which isn't a valid class name

A couple of old closed bugs ([#7](https://github.com/paypal/sdk-core-php/issues/7), [#34](https://github.com/paypal/sdk-core-php/issues/34)) mention Zend Optimizer, which is now known as OpCache, which could well be your culprit - it has a pair of settings [`opcache.save_comments` and `opcache.load_comments`](http://php.net/manual/en/opcache.configuration.php#ini.opcache.save-comments) which must be set to On to save docblocks (`/** ... */` comments) in memory. Since the Annotations relied on by the SDK are in such docblocks, if you've installed OpCache, or changed the value of that setting, your application will break.

Comment: Your answer looks very logical and close to what I figured while searching on different forums and saw here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24220031/paypal-rest-api-issue-in-ppmodel-php-on-line-51

However, can you suggest me how to disable or give me any pointers to fix this Zend Optimizer or OpCache issue?

Comment: @WaliHassan Is the link to the two INI directives not pointer enough? Or if you look [higher up the same manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/opcache.configuration.php#ini.opcache.enable) you'll see the setting to turn it off completely (although that shouldn't be necessary, and will just slow down your code).

Comment: I agree you are right but just checked my server and I can not see the opcache installed. the only thing installed is ionCube.

 `php -v
PHP 5.3.29 (cli) (built: Jan 11 2015 05:19:17) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
    with the ionCube PHP Loader v4.6.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2014, by ionCube Ltd., and
    with Zend Guard Loader v3.3, Copyright (c) 1998-2010, by Zend Technologies`

Comment: @WaliHassan So, maybe try disabling that? I'm sure it can't be that hard to find documentation for "disable ioncube".

Comment: Thanks but updating the SDK was required with REST API SDK Paypal

Comment: opcache.save_comments=1 and
opcache.load_comments=1 fixed the the issue for me